# Defensive goals and assists

Tags: football, trivia, english-premier-league

Yesterday in Liverpool’s 5-0 win versus Watford, Liverpool defenders scored 7 goals or assists.

Is this a record, in the premier league or, for that matter, any form of pro-football?